# Can $\mathbb{R}$ be obtained as union of disjoint translations of a dense subset?

Tags: general-topology

Doing some homework I had to find out maximal subgroups of $\mathbb{R}$ and my first approach was that subgroups of $\mathbb{R}$ are discrete or dense and, of course, a maximal subgroup $G$ can't be discrete and $\mathbb{R}/G \simeq \mathbb{Z}_p$ for some $p$ prime number. Since $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is cyclic then there should be $u \in \mathbb{R}$ for which
$$\mathbb{R} = G \bigsqcup (u + G) \bigsqcup (2u + G) \bigsqcup \cdots \bigsqcup ((p-1)u + G) $$

and so I turned out to prove

> There isn't any proper dense subset $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ for which $\mathbb{R}$ can be obtained my means of union of a finite number of disjoint translations of $X$.

I accomplished my original problem in another way, although I couldn't prove or disprove my original approach.

Comment: You want $X$ to be a *proper* subset :-)

Comment: No quotient group of $\mathbb{R}$ can be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, because $\mathbb{R}$ is $p$-divisible - that is, any non-zero element of $\mathbb{R}$ is $p$ times some other non-zero element of $\mathbb{R}$, so any homomorphism $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ has to map everything to zero.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Yes, it was almost my "another way".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let
$$
X_n \;=\; \Bigl(\bigl[n,n+\tfrac12\bigr)\cap \mathbb{Q}\Bigr) \,\cup\, \Bigl(\bigl[n+\tfrac12,n+1\bigr)-\mathbb{Q}\Bigr)
$$
for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, and let $X = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} X_n$.  Then $X$ is clearly dense, and $\mathbb{R}$ is the disjoint union of $X$ and $X+\tfrac12$.

Answer (score 2):

Pick any $A\subset[0,1)$ such that $[0,1)\subseteq\overline A$ and $[0,1)\subseteq\overline{[0,1)\setminus A}$.

Then $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z}(A+2n)\cup\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z}([0,1]\setminus A+2n+1)$ works.